# Displaying different data to different users in Python

Tags: python

I'm making a (rather) simple card game in Python, I have everything set up for the game, I just need a way to deal with multiple users, and display something (the cards in the hand) to the user that they're assigned to. I've seen some responses about Twisted, but that doesn't seem to solve my problem, at least how it was presented. I'm looking for something like -

```
print player1cards to player1
print player2cards to player2
```

but in whatever format is needed.

Comment: How are these multiple users playing the game? On one computer? Multiple user accounts? Multiple computers? Over the internet?

Comment: Maintain a data structure (list or some such) for each player. Then, look in the corresponding data structure

Answer (score 0):

Well, the obvious answer here would be to have a class `Player` :

```
class Player:
     playercards = []
```

Another way is to assign each player a name:

```
class Player:
     name = ""
```

And then have a `Gameserver` class :

```
class Gameserver:
    cards = {'Player1':['4Clubs', 'QClubs'], .....}

    def getCards(name):
        return cards[name]
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
gameserver = GameServer()

#Initialize and blablabla
........


x = Player("Player1")
x.showHand() 
#the line above would basically do the following:
#print gameserver.getCards(x.name())
```